# Phpmyadmin rows add automatically

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a database with 2 table and some fields and ID is Primary Key. On phpmyadmin whenever i click on my table the rows add automatically with unique ID... Do you know why it happen?

Thanks

Comment: When you click where, the Browse tab? That's strange as that shouldn't be adding anything. Can you show us the table structure?

Comment: When i click on table on left sidebar...Here is my table structure: ID>int(11) , brand>varchar(256), cpa>smallint, ftds>int(11), web>varchar page>varchar, ftddate>date

Comment: I'm still having trouble reproducing this. Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? If you try on the demo server at http://demo.phpmyadmin.net does the problem occur there?